# The narrowing of a column of water from a faucet $r=r_0\left(1+\frac{2gs}{u^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{4}}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, differentiation, flow, continuum-mechanics

A tap (faucet) pushes out a stream of water of circular cross section of radius r0
directly downwards at an exit speed u.

Assuming a constant downward acceleration, g, of water, the
radius of the water column and a distance s below the tap is given by
$$r=r_0\left(1+\frac{2gs}{u^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{4}}$$
(This can be obtained by applyting XUVAT to the continuity eq. $\pi r^2v=\pi r^2u$, nothing tricky here.)

Use the equation above to explain why the stream from a tap narrows
very quickly as it exits the tap before forming a more uniform column far below.

---

My attempt:

For small $s$, we have $\frac{2gs}{u^2}<<1$ for constant $g, r_0$ and a given $u$, binomial expansion gives
$$r \approx r_0\left(1-\frac{gs}{2u^2}\right)$$
Differentiating gives $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}\approx -\frac{r_0g}{2u^2}=const.$$
For the stream to narrow quickly, $|\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}| \to large$ but this is true only if $r_0g>>u^2$ and in general this needs not to be the case as you can have a small $r_0$ and large $u_0$?

Similarly for a uniform column well below the tap:
$$r=r_0\left(\frac{2gs}{u^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\underbrace{\left(\frac{u^2}{2gs}+1\right)^{-\frac{1}{4}}}_{\frac{u^2}{2gs}<<1; so \approx 1} \approx r_0\left (\frac{2g}{u^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{4}}s^{-\frac{1}{4}}$$
then
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial s} \approx -\left(\frac{r_0}{4}\right)\left(\frac{2g}{u^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{4}}s^{-\frac{5}{4}}$$
$|\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}| \to small$ when $s \to large$ which is better than the previous result but I am not sure how valid my argument is.